# Updated from 16.04 to 18.04 - missing topbar and launcher

Tags: 18.04

Updated from 16.04 to 18.04 and had a few hiccups along the way (partial upgrade available).

Now I've got no topbar or launcher. Already tried enabling Unity launcher in CCM, but no luck.

The other odd thing is that terminal says I'm on 18.04, but the login screen still says 16.04.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Appreciate that this is one month old now, but I ran into it when searching for another problem I'm having.  In my case, I had the reverse problem: an error indicated that my upgrade had failed and said it was going to roll back, but it didn't.  Anyway, did you run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade immediately after the install?